# how to use OpenCV-Python in ROS

Tags: ros, yolo, opencv, python

**using yolo with opencv-python in ROS environment**
I want to use yolo with Opencv-python in ROS to control a camera and realize object detection.
Now I've already know how to run yolo in Windows,but I don't know how to run it in ROS.
how can I port my code in ROS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ROS is a framework for easily combining different libraries, which provide interfaces not defined as header files, but as 'nodes', called by 'launch files' (xml scripts). 
This implies that you want to both run Yolo on a video/camera feed, but that you want it to interface with other libraries or code. If you don't, then you don't need ROS.

ROS(v1), pretty much right now, runs best on Ubuntu. It works both natively or in virtualbox. ROS2 has support for windows, but if you have issues with it, that is a different question.

To make a ROS node for your python code, first put it all into a separate class/module; the ROS node should only have *interfacing boilerplate* between the "real code" and communication. Assuming you're using [`usb_cam_node`](https://wiki.ros.org/usb_cam) to get the camera feed, the data will be published on the 'topic' `<camera_name>/image` [[`sensor_msgs/Image`](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html)], where `<camera_name>` is a `usb_cam_node` parameter. A topic is like a global variable between all ROS nodes, read from by a `Subscriber` (with callback) and published to by a `Publisher`.

Then you have to decide what to publish from it. Because it's yolo, perhaps you want the bounding boxes for each detection. There are a bunch of pre-defined ROS messages (these are the (static and strongly typed) "types" of the 'topics'). One is [`geometry_msgs/PolygonStamped`](https://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PolygonStamped.html), which allows you to specify the corners of a box, and stamp it.

Here is some example code, taken from the [wiki](https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29)

```python
# yolo_boxes_node.py
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Header
from geometry_msgs.msg import PolygonStamped, Point32
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
# This is your custom yolo code
import my_yolo as yolo # Assuming a method like as follows:
# yolo.evaluate(img_frame) -> 
#   boxes ([x,y,width,hight] list), confidences (list), classids (list)

# Subscribers
#     img_sub (sensor_msgs/Image): "webcam/image" #Comment: we document a name for the sub, the type, and the default topic for it

# Publishers
#     boxes_pub (geometry_msgs/PolygonStamped): "webcam/yolo/boxes"

# Publishers
boxes_pub = None

# Parameters
frequency = 100.0 # Hz

# Global Variables
img_frame = None
header = None

def img_callback(data): # data of type Image
    global img_frame
    global header
    img_frame = data.data
    header = data.header

def timer_callback(event): # This is to process data at a fixed rate, perhaps different from camera framerate
    # Convert img_frame somehow if needed
    if img_frame is None or boxes_pub is None:
        return
    boxes, confidences, classids = yolo.evaluate(img_frame)
    for b in boxes:
        msg = PolygonStamped()
        msg.header = header # You could use the header differently
        msg.polygon.points.append(Point32(x=b[0],y=b[1]))
        msg.polygon.points.append(Point32(x=b[0]+b[2],y=b[1]))
        msg.polygon.points.append(Point32(x=b[0],y=b[1]+b[3]))
        msg.polygon.points.append(Point32(x=b[0]+b[2],y=b[1]+b[3]))
        boxes_pub.publish(msg)

# In your main function, you subscribe to topics
def yolo_boxes_node():
    # Init ROS
    rospy.init_node('yolo_boxes_node', anonymous=True)

    # Parameters
    if rospy.has_param('~frequency'):
        frequency = rospy.get_param('~frequency')

    # Subscribers
    # Each subscriber has the topic, topic type, AND the callback!
    rospy.Subscriber('webcam/image', Image, img_callback)
    # Rarely/never need to hold onto the object with a variable: 
    #     img_sub = rospy.Subscriber(...)
    rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(1.0/frequency), timer_callback)

    # Publishers
    boxes_pub = rospy.Publisher('webcam/yolo/boxes', PolygonStamped, queue_size = 100)
    # queue_size increases as buffer for msgs; if you have 1000s of boxes, might need bigger

    # spin() simply keeps python from exiting until this node is stopped
    # This is an infinite loop, the only code that gets ran are callbacks
    rospy.spin()
    # NO CODE GOES AFTER THIS, NONE! USE TIMER CALLBACKS!
    # unless you need to clean up resource allocation, close(), etc when program dies

if __name__ == '__main__':
    yolo_boxes_node()
```

Ergo an example xml launch file might be:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- my_main_program.launch -->
<launch>
  <!--
    Pub: <camera_name>/image [sensor_msgs/Image]
  -->
  <node name="usb_cam_node" type="usb_cam_node" pkg="usb_cam" output="screen" restart="true">
    <param name="camera_name" value="webcam"/>
    <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video0"/>
  </node>

  <!--
    img_sub: webcam/image [sensor_msgs/Image]
    boxes_pub: webcam/yolo/boxes [geometry_msgs/PolygonStamped]
  -->
  <node name="yolo_boxes_node" type="yolo_boxes_node" pkg="my_pkg" output="screen">
    <param name="frequency" value="30.0"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to understand your answer,but I realized I lack of some knowledge of ROS so that I can't understand some of infomation,I will see this answer again after I get some knowledge of ROS.Thanks again!

Comment: Feel free to ask questions about things which are not explained clearly enough, and I can improve upon it. ROS is just a system of connecting different programs together, to share data, using messages. If you know what you want to connect, and how, the ROS part is not too difficult.